# Prove that if a set $S$ has an accumulation point at $0$, it contains a sequence of nonzero terms which converge to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I met this problem in exercises in regards to *Complex Analysis*, and felt very confused.

Our aim to establish that, if a set $S$ has an accumulation point at $0$, it contains a sequence of nonzero terms which converge to $0$. This fact proves a rather important corollary: If a power series equals zero at the points of a set with an accumulation point at the origin, the power series is identically zero.

1. Since accumulation point is just another way to express limit point, it means the set $S$ has infintely many points surrounding $0$.
2. Then, we can take $\lvert z_{1}\rvert $ equal to any real number
3. Take $\lvert z_{2}\rvert = 1/2 * \lvert z_{1}\rvert $ Repeat the steps and we have a sequence converge to $0$.

Now how does the above steps contribute to proving the power series must be identically $0$ if there is an accumulation point at the origin?

Comment: Why do you think your points belong to the given set $S$?

Comment: This statement follows from the definition of accumulation point. It is so obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct.  The points you construct are not necessarily in $S$.

Take $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$, $\epsilon \gt 0$ Then we have $z_1 \in S$ such that $0 \lt |z_1 - z| \lt \epsilon$.  Now start dividing $\epsilon$ by $2$. You get $z_2, z_3, ... $ etc. (all in $S$) such that

$$0 \lt |z_n - z| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2^{n-1}}$$ for every $n = 1,2,3, \dots$

This is the sequence you are looking for.

All in all this statement is obvious, it just follows from the definition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point